# Regex match a string if its in the end

Tags: c#, .net, regex

The following regular expression

```
 (cm)[\s,]
```

mathches

```
cm,
cm followed by space
```

how do i also make it match cm if cm is the last word in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USe end of the line anchor.

```
(cm)(?:[\s,]|$)
```

You don't need to have a capturing group.

```
cm(?:[\s,]|$)
```

This matches `cm,` or  `cm<space>` or last `cm`

Answer (score 1):

```
cm(?=\s|$|,)
```

Try this.This should work.